# Algebra + Real Analysis video lectures

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request, online-resources

I'm an undergraduate taking graduate courses beginning a research project. I don't have much time but want to brush up on my Algebra and real analysis at a graduate level. Does anybody know any good video lectures on the subjects, I need some more knowledge of measure theory for the analysis and semi-direct products and splitting etc. My reading list is way over filled and I've had classes on these subjects before so videos would be best.

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

Abstract Algebra:
[Harvard](http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra)

Real Analysis:
[Harvey Mudd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqEyWLGvvdw)

Note: These are both targeted at the undergraduate audience but I think it is a valuable tool for those reviewing for graduate school.

Comment: Having done both of these [in prep for undergrad], I'm a fan of the Harvey Mudd lectures but not so much on the Harvard ones. The grad student does not have anywhere near the presentation ability of the lecturer, and so every third lecture I felt completely lost. (Also, going in without a very firm geometry background makes the middle section a lot less compelling)

Comment: The class of Benedict Gross is so beautiful.